# What does "rooting for my alt" mean in Stranger Things?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This quote is from Stranger Things season 4, episode 1, 43 minute 10 seconds mark by Fred Benson:

> Eh, I'm still rooting for my alt.

What does 'alt' mean in this context?

Maybe it has something to do with the paper, as he showed Nancy ‘The Tigers Lose the Championship Game’ paper while saying this quote.

Fred Benson, portrayed by Logan Riley Bruner, was a recurring character in the fourth season of Stranger Things. He was a student at Hawkins High School, and worked on the school newspaper.

Comment: You've tagged this "meaning-in-context", but you've provided no context. Please tell us what's going on in the situation, and provide maybe a paragraph or two of the dialogue before this. Don't expect everyone to have a Netflix account and go watch it themselves.

Comment: “Maybe I’m missing
something, but why can’t Jonathan come down for spring break?” Asked Fred. “Because.” Nancy said
“Because why?” Fred asked. “Because a lot of reasons.” Nancy said. “Curious.” Fred said. “Um, do you
mind if I take a crack at this, Candace?” Asked Nancy. “Um, go ahead. All yours.” Said Candace  “You
said there’s lots of reasons he’s not coming. Such as?” Fred asked and he wasn’t gonna stop until he
found out why.

Comment: “Why are you so noisy?” Nancy asked. “Call
It journalistic instinct.” Said Fred. “Okay, well, there’s no story here, if that’s what your after.” Nancy told
him and then resumed. “His mom works, so he has to watch over his brother. On top of that, he’s not
early decisions like me, so he’s waiting on his acceptance letter, and he wants to be there when it
comes. Which I totally get.”

Comment: And he’ll never back down
from what’s right, what’s moral. No matter the pressure, no matter the personal cost… That’s why I love him. Everything between us is… Perfect.” Nancy said. “Eh,
I’m still rooting for my alt.” Said Fred, as he showed Nancy ‘The Tigers Lose the Championship Game’

Comment: Thanks! Please [edit] your question and put that information in the body of the question. Comments are for discussion about the question, not information essential to answering it.

Comment: The term **alt** is used in online games and realities to signify a duplicate account by the human – an 'alternative identity'. I can't find any reference to support it, but in social media can be called a [sock puppet](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538515/what-do-you-call-social-network-accounts-owned-by-the-same-person).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In that context, "[alt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alt)" is an abbreviation of "alternate".

Fred has two newspaper front page layouts. The first says, "TIGERS WIN!!!", while the second says, "TIGERS DEVOURED - Blood And Tears Shed". It is common practice for newspaper editors to prepare two layouts in advance when the outcome of a major event won't be known until late in the evening (just before press time). At the point in time when the outcome is finally known, they then use the prepared layout that applies to what actually happened.

So when Fred says, "I'm still rooting for my alt", he's moving his focus from the first layout to the second, meaning he's rooting for the Tigers to lose, which would result in being able to use his *alternate* (second) layout.

Comment: Just based on the words, I wouldn't assume the character is "moving his focus". The "I'm still rooting for" expression (in my experience) is preceded by an implicit "Despite the odds" or equivalent, meaning that the speaker is hoping their desired outcome will occur while acknowledging that it's not likely.

Comment: @nobody I watched the episode. He's quite clearly moving his focus.